# How to import multi-module project in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework-2.0, sbt

I'm used to Spring and Maven projects where I set up a multi-module project in Maven with projects like:

```
app-web
app-models
app-services
app-common
```

I'm now getting into using [Play Framework 2](http://www.playframework.com/) (Scala) and [sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/).

Is there a similar concept with Play and sbt that I could group all of these projects into a single IntelliJ IDEA solution and sbt?

Answer (score 8):

[IntelliJ IDEA 13](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) (the latest version is **13.1.3**) comes with [the built-in SBT support](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/#Scala), and  [the Ultimate edition adds Play support](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/play_framework.html).

A multi-module sbt project can be imported to IDEA and is fully supported out of the box however it's Play-based or not (they're sbt projects after all).

You should try it out yourself with the following very simplistic build file **build.sbt** (or just generate a Play project with `play new` or better now `activator new [your-project-name] play-scala`):

```
lazy val a, b, c = project
```

and the following `project/build.properties`:

```
sbt.version=0.13.5
```

Nothing but these two above files are needed to get you started with sbt/activator.

In IDEA, open the project using `File > Open...` and select `build.sbt`.

[image]

Click `OK` to see another window where you specify additional configuration options for the project. Then the modules show up.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You probably wouldn't be able to group them into one single project in idea but you could have multiple projects for sure:

in your project/Build.scala:

```
{

  val baseDependencies = Seq(
    "org1" % "dep" % "latest.integration",
    "org2" % "dep2" % "version"
  )

  val modelDependencies = baseDependencies ++ Seq("org3" % "dep3" % "version")

  val appWeb = play.Project("app-web", "1.0", baseDependencies)

  val appModels = play.Project("app-models", "1.0", modelDependencies, path = file("modules/models"))

  val app = play.Project("app", "1.0", Nil).aggregate(appWeb, appModels)
}
```

In this case, you'll have a regular app called "app-web", a module appModels under modules/models without the project directory and regular confs like application.conf, and an aggregated app called "app".

When you start the play console you could switch to certain projects by typing "project (name)". For example you could type "project app-web" and then "idea" to generate the app-web project solution for idea. You can also switch to project "app" where all commands entered under it will be applied to all sub-projects.

For more, check the documentation here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/SBTSubProjects